# Git bash crashed my Dell laptop. it does not restart at all

Tags: windows, git-bash

I downloaded Git Bash then my laptop crashed once it got installed. It won't restart at all.. it is windows 10.. I am using DEll. what should i do?

by crash i mean my laptop is off completely.

Comment: Please better describe what *crashed* means? And are you sure it's git bash related? It's more likely another fault like a defunct SSD and git bash just triggered it. And https://superuser.com/ might be a better place for this question.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "It won't restart at all". If the computer does not even post or send any life signal upon pressing power this is most likely a hardware problem.